# Changing asdf installed elasticsearch settings on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, asdf

I have installed elasticsearch `7.x (7.10.2)` and `8.x (8.1.2)` successfully with asdf and both appear to run on my local system without issue.

- Version `7.x` has security disabled, runs as it should, and allows my development apps to make requests
- Version `8.x` has security enabled (by default, I assume), runs as it should, but I cannot make requests to the application (curl or otherwise).

I'm unable to find out where elasticsearch was installed on my local machine and how to change the security settings to make `8.x` work like `7.x`.

There's not much documentation that does along with [asdf-elasticsearch](https://github.com/asdf-community/asdf-elasticsearch) and almost all google searches land with articles about homebrew-installed elasticsearch (which ceased as the package manager after elasticsearch 7.x)

How can you find out where elasticsearch was installed by asdf on a mac and how can you change the security settings on the `8.x` version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the location of the installation

- Using terminal: `cd ~/.asdf/installs/elasticsearch`

To allow for all anonymous requests, edit the following

- Move to: `cd ~/.asdf/installs/elasticsearch/config`
- Using your editor of choice: `code elasticsearch.yml`
- Edit the value of `true` to `false`

```
# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Note: This will remove all security features of elasticsearch on your local (or whatever server) you choose. YMMV